# How to get correct order at y axis (matplotlob (P 2.7) correct

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know why the order of the y axis is random (see screenshot). I'm plotting just x and y values from a text file with value pairs and want to have the y axis starting from minimum and ending with maximum value. In my case there is the smallest number (3) in the middle of the y axis plot. How can I correct this misorder?

txt-file:

```
1,5
2,3
3,5
4,3
5,7
6,3
7,5
8,3
9,5
10,3
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('example.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)  # 1000 ms = 1 sec (updating)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**I found out that editing the following two lines of code helps !!!**

*Before:*
xs.append(x)
ys.append(y)

*After:*
xs.append(float(x))
ys.append(float(y))

[image]

Comment: Short answer: Don't try to plot strings. Use numbers instead.

Comment: This is not a duplicate by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a FiveThirtyEight style on the line

```
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

Just remove it to use the normal plotting style.

Comment: Thx mate ! See my edit above... i found another solution

Comment: that only makes the values as floats thought. It doesn't change the plotting style

Comment: I cant give reasons for this but it changes the plotting style ! Try it out